# Bootstrap table with fixed length and content warping inside td

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstap css for a table. I need a fixed lenght table where the contents inside the table (ie..,td) should wrap into multiple line if needed.

Below is the snippet of my code which is not working. content of td is not wrapped inside a cell of fixed length.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Table</h2>
      <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>  
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table fixed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Firstname</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Lastname</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Johddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddn</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Mary</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Moe</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">July</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Dooley</td>
            <td >july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Output i as in image. the content of the cell is overflowing.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS

```
table {
       -ms-word-break: break-all;
       word-break: break-all;    
}
```

Read more about word-break here :

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because when you type like 'sssssssssssssssssssssssss' it thinks it's one word. Even responsive designs don't break words. But if you want to break one word as well, you should try this code as following.

```
td{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word wrap css in the td

```
  word-wrap: break-word;
```